# Grouping rows based on the True value Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, geopandas

I have Point geodataframe with True and False values. Geodataframe has 48 True/False columns and each row has only one True at whatever column and False all other columns. I would like to group the points based on the True values in columns **foo** and **bar** as the example below. For example points A and D are True at **bar** column, so they group together and points B and C are True at column **foo** therefore they group together. Point geometry should be preserved as they may be used in analysis at some point.

```
from shapely.geometry import Point, Polygon
import geopandas

polygons = geopandas.GeoSeries({
    'foo': Polygon([(6, 6), (7, 16), (13, 14), (13, 9)]),
    'bar': Polygon([(15, 18), (14, 15), (17, 10), (21, 9)]),
})

points = [Point(16, 13), Point(7, 8), Point(10, 12), Point(16,14)]
pnts = geopandas.GeoDataFrame(geometry=points, index=['p1', 'p2', 'p3', 'p4'])
pnts = pnts.assign(**{key: pnts.within(geom) for key, geom in 
polygons.items()})

out[]

       geometry    foo    bar
p1  POINT (16 13)  False   True
p2    POINT (7 8)   True  False
p3  POINT (10 12)   True  False
p4  POINT (16 14)  False   True
```

Expected output should be:

```
    geometry
foo POINT(7 8)
    POINT(10,12)
bar POINT (16 13)
    POINT (16 14)
```

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: It is still unclear what you're trying to do. Are all the `True`/`False` columns mutually exclusive? Do you want to do something with the points after you group them?

Comment: Thanks @PMende, I updated the question, hope it is clear now.

Answer (score 1):

You may do it this way. Lets say all your geodataframes col are in list `columns`.

```
columns = df.columns.tolist() # get all the column names in a list
columns.remove("geometry")  # make sure only those column names are present that contain 
                        # geodataframe i.e. 48 columns in your case and thats why removed column name "geometry"

df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns = ["geometry", "new_col"]) # created an empty dataframe so that we can append new rows to it

for col in columns:
    df_subset = df.loc[df[col],["geometry"]] 
    df_subset["new_col"] = col
    df1 = pd.concat([df1, df_subset])
df1.index = df1.new_col
df1.drop(["new_col"], axis = 1)
```

The result will look something like this.

```
           geometry
new_col 
foo POINT (7 8)
foo POINT (10 12)
bar POINT (16 13)
bar POINT (16 14)
```

Comment: Thanks @MNA, it is a good approach, however I have 48 columns which requires some manual work with this approach. I wanted more automated approach if possible. I updated my question.

Comment: edited my answer based on your comments and changes in question.

Comment: Thanks @MNA for your help. If I run your code it gives 

     AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'remove'. I added all code in the question so you can try.

Comment: @Sher: edited the answer. Basically I am having all the column names in the list for it to run in loop.

Comment: I tried, but got keyerror: 'foo'. I would appreciate if you give some comments to your code.

Comment: @Sher gave some comments for your understanding. Of course you may have to make some changed based on your dataframe. This code is based on whatever inputs you have provided.

Comment: thank you so much, this worked. Sorry for the late reply, I was in the field.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use pandas.where :

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice([True, False], 10).reshape(-1, 2), columns=['A', 'B'])

A_result = df.where(df["A"] == True).dropna()
B_result = df.where(df["B"] == True).dropna()
```

Comment: Thanks @Guillaume Hubert, it is a good approach, however I have 48 columns and wanted to check if there is more efficient way of doing this. I updated my question.